# Edit is disabled?

Tags: support, editing, suggested-edits

I noticed that the *Edit* button is disabled (greyed out and not clickable) when viewing posts:

[image]

I'm having trouble locating information on why that might happen (Googling is returning lots of irrelevant hits).

It looks like the edits over the last day or so have been accepted, and none have been rejected. The account info can be found at https://superuser.com/users/173513/jww?tab=activity&sort=suggestions.

The question in question is at [having an issue with homebrew brew doctor](https://superuser.com/q/839421). I think it needs its title fixed "Issue with X" is not very helpful), and it needs some formatting in the body (it looks like it was copied but not quoted).

Have I managed to reach a limit? Or has my account been penalized?

Comment: A link to the question would be nice. I wonder if there was already a pending edit at that time

Comment: @JourneymanGeek - The question in question was added to my question (???).

Comment: Unquestionably. And its as I suspected, though being a mod *and* a high rep user, checking it would have been annoying

Answer (score 3):

It looks like everything is working as expected. Hovering the mouse over *Edit* shows a message similar to "Another edit is awaiting approval for this post...".

Sorry about the false alarm. I've got over 10K on Stack Overflow so I don't encounter this workflow.